# Tabla SQL mal hecha, transferir datos

Tags: sql, sql-server

tengo una tabla mal diseñada y necesito transferir a otra nueva que está bien diseñada.

La tabla contiene clientes pero en la misma columna, en vez de en fila.

| Cliente_ID | Nombre | Apellido | Nombre2 | Apellido2 | Nombre3 | Apellido3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Carlos | Chacón | Agatón | Merino | Abram | Laboy |

Necesito que los datos queden de esta forma, pasando los datos de la misma fila y relacionar los clientes.

| Cliente_ID | Nombre | Apellido |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Carlos | Chacón |
| 1 | Agatón | Merino |
| 1 | Abram | Laboy |

Por ahora hago algo manual de esta forma, pero hay miles de filas para hacer

```sql
INSERT INTO CLIENTES
    (
        [Nombre],
        [Apellido],
    )
    (SELECT
         Nombre2,
         Apellido2,
     FROM CLIENTES
     WHERE Cliente_ID = @Id)
```

Pero de esta manera tendría que ir cambiando el @Id y tardaría muchísimo.

Comment: ¨no entiendo para que seleccionas el id, si igual tenes que generar id nuevos para todas?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: No, estaba pensando agregar una columna que identifique a esos clientes, y con ese número insertar y relacionarlos, se llama "Cliente_ID"

Comment: A lo que entiendo @gbianchi creo que `Nombre`-`Apellido`, `Nombre2`-`Apellido2`... están relacionados a un mismo **id**, por eso están en la misma fila.

Comment: Lo que intente hacer en ese insert es agarrar los datos de Nombre2, Apellido2 y pasarlos a una nueva fila, pero insertarlos en Nombre y Apellido, así después borro las columnas mal hechas como Nombre2, Apellido2 sin necesidad de crear otra tabla

Comment: Con programación sería muy fácil convertir esa data, ¿conoces algún lenguaje como PHP?

Comment: Estaba pensando en intentar pasar los datos con C#, pero no se me ocurre el algoritmo por ahora

Comment: Espera.. no entiendo nada... tenes una tabla mal hecha.. es una tabla real? es una tabla productiva de un sistema? si es asi, necesitas un proceso, porque seguro tenes que arreglar mil datos mas... si no es asi, explica bien como tenes los datos, y como queres que queden, que hacer con los id y con todo para ayudarte.. igual, si no es una tabla real, tirala y empeza de vuelta...

Comment: Es una tabla SQL real de Clientes que son pasajeros, pero están mal relacionados y contiene los datos de los pasajeros en la misma columna (Nombre, NombredePax2, NombreDePax3) etc.
Lo que quiero hacer es pasar Nombre2, Nombre3 etc. a "Nombre" en una fila nueva y relacionarlo con el ID.

Comment: el id no es unico entonces? mostra que queres de resultado.. porque si no, alcanza con una con la misma consulta, sin el where, y agregando el id....

Comment: Claro, "Cliente_ID" no es único, lo cree para relacionar los pasajeros

Comment: por ejemplo, tengo esto: https://i.imgur.com/bnVja3H.png
y quiero que quede así https://i.imgur.com/7g1yT9t.png

Comment: Eso es un insert trivial como el que te describi arriba.. lo intentaste???? como son 4 columnas, hacelo a mano y listo...

Comment: Son 4 columnas, pero miles de filas así... o sea son muchísimos datos, no mostré la tabla original.

Comment: no importan las filas.. importan las columnas.. son 4..son dos querys... cual es tu problema con las filas? cuanto son miles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quizás podrías llevar, en un primer paso, a la nueva tabla todos los "Nombre" y "Apellido". En un segundo paso, añadirías a la nueva tabla todos los "Nombre2" y "Apellido2"... y así sucesivamente como tantos nombres y apellidos hayan en una fila. En la tabla nueva también podrías agregar, si es necesario conocerlo, el ID de la antigua tabla y el número de posición que ocupaba el nombre y apellido en la antigua tabla.

Lo que pretendo decir es que de una tabla así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Puedes obtener otra con el IdAntiguo y su nuevo Id:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con un código más o menos así:

```
    DECLARE @NUMREG INT,
        @CURREG INT

/*Initialize Variables*/
SELECT @NUMREG = (SELECT Count(ID) FROM TablaAntigua)


SET @CURREG = 1
WHILE @CURREG <= @NUMREG 

BEGIN  --   Una primera vuelta para Nombre y Apellido:
    INSERT INTO TablaNueva
    (
        [Id],
        [Nombre],
        [Apellido],
        [IdAntiguo],
        [Posicion]
    )
    (SELECT
         @CURREG,
         Nombre,
         Apellido,
         Id AS IdAntiguo,
         1
     FROM TablaAntigua WHERE Id = @CURREG)
    SET @CURREG = @CURREG + 1
END


--        REPETIR CON NOMBRE2 Y APELLIDO2:
SET @CURREG = 1
WHILE @CURREG <= @NUMREG 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO TablaNueva
    (
        [Id],
        [Nombre],
        [Apellido],
        [IdAntiguo],
        [Posicion]
    )
    (SELECT
         @CURREG + @NUMREG,
         Nombre2,
         Apellido2,
         Id AS IdAntiguo,
         2
     FROM TablaAntigua WHERE Id = @CURREG)
    SET @CURREG = @CURREG + 1
END

--        REPETIR CON NOMBRE3 Y APELLIDO3:
SET @CURREG = 1
WHILE @CURREG <= @NUMREG 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO TablaNueva
    (
        [Id],
        [Nombre],
        [Apellido],
        [IdAntiguo],
        [Posicion]
    )
    (SELECT
         @CURREG + 2 * @NUMREG,
         Nombre3,
         Apellido3,
         Id AS IdAntiguo,
         3
     FROM TablaAntigua WHERE Id = @CURREG)
    SET @CURREG = @CURREG + 1
END
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, tu respuesta me ayudo mucho!

Answer (score 1):

No necesitas ir insertando fila por fila, por lo tanto no necesitas la condición impuesta en el WHERE. Tampoco hace falta hacer varias consultas para cada grupo de columnas. Se puede hacer todo con una simple instrucción que convierte las columnas en filas.

```
INSERT INTO CLIENTES_NUEVO
    (
        Cliente_ID,
        [Nombre],
        [Apellido]
    )
SELECT  cl.Cliente_ID
        c.Nombre,
        c.Apellido,
FROM CLIENTES cl
CROSS APPLY( VALUES ( Nombre , Apellido)
                    ( Nombre2, Apellido2),
                    ( Nombre3, Apellido3))C( Nombre, Apellido)
WHERE c.Nombre <> '';--Verifica que no sea una cadena vacía o nulo
```

Lo que convierte las columnas en filas es el constructor de tablas VALUES. El `CROSS APPLY` nos permite hacer referencia a columnas de las tablas anteriores.

Sin embargo, esto sigue pareciendo un mal diseño puesto que debes tener una tabla de Clientes y una distinta que incluya todos los nombres que pueda tener cada cliente.

```
CREATE TABLE Clientes(
    Cliente_ID int,
    Atributo_X varchar(100),
    Atributo_Y varchar(100),
    Atributo_Z varchar(100)
);

CREATE TABLE Nombres_Clientes(
    Cliente_ID  int,
    Nombre_ID   int,
    Nombre      varchar(200),
    Apellido    varchar(200)
)

    INSERT INTO Nombres_Clientes
        (
            Cliente_ID,
            Nombre_ID,
            [Nombre],
            [Apellido]
        )
    SELECT  cl.Cliente_ID,
            c.Nombre_ID,
            c.Nombre,
            c.Apellido
    FROM CLIENTES cl
    CROSS APPLY( VALUES ( 1, Nombre , Apellido)
                        ( 2, Nombre2, Apellido2),
                        ( 3, Nombre3, Apellido3))C( Nombre_ID, Nombre, Apellido)
    WHERE c.Nombre <> '';--Verifica que no sea una cadena vacía o nulo
```

Comment: Creo que los dato que pone son a forma de ejemplo,
Pero tu solución me parece genial.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que utilizar el comando while y generar esos atributos de forma dinámica, prueba de la siguiente manera :

```
DECLARE @MAXCOLUMN INT,
        @CURREN INT
 
/*Initialize Variables*/
SELECT @MAXCOLUMN = COUNT(COLUMN_NAME) FROM MainDB.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'SomeTable';
SET @CURRENTCOLUMN = 1
 
/*BEGIN LOOP*/
WHILE @CURRENTCOLUMN <= @MAXCOLUMN / 2

BEGIN
    INSERT INTO CLIENTES2
    (
        [Nombre],
        [Apellido],
    )
    (SELECT
         'Nombre' + STR(@CURRENTCOLUMN),
         'Apellido' + STR(@CURRENTCOLUMN),
     FROM CLIENTES)
 
/*Next Record*/
SET @CURRENTCOLUMN = @CURRENTCOLUMN + 1
 
END
```

Comment: Por qué `@CurrentRecord <= @MaxRecord/2` ? Estás recorriendo sólo la mitad?

Comment: Gracias por preguntar Arriel, quedó mal el nombre de records, entiendo que por la tabla mal diseñada el intenta recorrer las columnas y no las filas.
Tiene 2 atributos por "Cliente" por eso divido las columnas entre dos porque por cada uno saca nombre y apellido.
No agregó mucho contexto y por eso intenté hacerlo lo más genérico posible

Comment: Gracias, estoy intentando todavía, lo adapte y me quedo salta este error ''Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Nombre' to data type int.''
Creo que se debe a que toma el int de @CURRENTCOLUMN al concatenar, lo que quiero hacer para ponerte más en contexto es algo así:
por ejemplo, tengo esto: https://i.imgur.com/bnVja3H.png y quiero que quede así https://i.imgur.com/7g1yT9t.png

Comment: Edité la respuesta @owlly puedes revisar ahora.
Porque quieres guardar el resto de las columnas como NULL values ? y guardar un ID que no es único? Te recomiendo por lo que veo que tu nueva tabla tenga 3 campos : id, nombre y apellido. Por cada registro tendrás un cliente

Comment: Porque necesito normalizarla para guardar en una nueva tabla bien hecha, necesito transferir esos datos a otra tabla y se me ocurrió esa forma, no sé si es la más óptima

Comment: Intenté seguir tu código pero porque no vas insertando en otra tabla, por ejemplo CLIENTES2 y luego te quedas con esa tabla ya lista?

Comment: Es que como tengo Nombre2, Nombre3, etc. en la misma columna me confunde bastante insertar los datos en la nueva tabla y relacionar esos pasajeros en la nueva tabla. y pienso que si los tengo solo en las columnas Nombre, Apellido es más fácil insertar en la nueva

Comment: Pero con el código que te pasé vas a tener una nueva tabla llamada clientes2 que ya es tu nueva tabla que quieres utilizar, sentite libre de cambiar lo que quieras del código para crear tu tabla con el nombre que quieras, no entiendo porque insertarías esos registros ahi con todos los campos en null y luego irías a una nueva tabla si puedo ir directo por una nueva tabla

Comment: Ahí probé ejecutando nuevamente, queda como en un bucle infinito parece

Comment: Pero cambiaste por los valores de tu caso de uso verdad? someTable por ejemplo es un placeholder, el código busca ser un ejemplo pero tienes que aplicar pequeñas cosas a tu caso de uso

Comment: Si, los cambie
SELECT @MAXCOLUMN = COUNT(COLUMN_NAME) FROM miDBNombre.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'CLIENTES';
COLUMN_NAME Y TABLE_NAME no los cambie, si cambio COLUMN_NAME por uno de la columna de mi bd me tira error.

Comment: Cual es el valor de @MAXCOLUMN, prueba imprimirlo, se me hace muy dificil ayudarte sin el resto del contexto. No tengo los puntos suficientes para iniciar una sala de chat y ayudarte

Comment: Me imprime 4 @MAXCOLUMN

Answer (score 0):

Buen día.
Aún estoy intentando aprender esto del SQL.
Pero algo sé de Excel.
Si exportas tu tabla  con todo y los encabezados y la guardas como archivo cvs
Después abres Excel (yo uso ver.365) y...
en la pestaña datos => obtener datos => de texto/cvs
busca la ubicación del archivo y después importar
En la ventana emergente selecciona transformar datos datos
Seleccionas las columnas que quieres cambiar en la tabla y en la pestaña transformar busca la opción:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Anulación de dinamización de columnas (que el nombrecito se las trae)
y le pides que haga eso precisamente, y te las deja como nuevas.
después le dices guardar y cargar.
guardas el archivo como cvs.
y lo importas a la nueva tabla.
Está fácil.
** OJO no puedes modificar mas de 1'000,000.00 filas y procura que el formato de las columnas que tengan números este en general o texto para evitar problemas **

<< Si alguien logra hacerlo en SQL me interesa ¡Puede ser más fácil! >>